# Algorithm to extract audio from an flv video(or any other video). How to go about it?

Tags: c++, python, audio, extract, flv

i currently want to write a program which can extract audio from an FLV video using either python or c++. I have no idea how to go about it? Is there some kind of a tutorial or anything that would help me? Please help me out here learn this.
Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to extract the audio you could simply use `mplayer` or `mencoder` ... or is your goal to write a program?

Comment: Writing a program interests me,if you got the resources to help me? Otherwise the libraries you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use MPlayer to do this, e.g.

```
mplayer video.flv -vo null -ao pcm:file=file.wav
```

So, you can use this in combination with calls from python (or C). Another way is to use [FFmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg/) which MPlayer uses internally.